# Use a regular expression to find url with different number params PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I'm in the process of moving content from one CMS to a different CMS. The url structure is different so I would like to replace some of the urls using php.

The old url is

`href="book-online?cid=123"`

where the value of cid is going to be different for each call to this link.

I want to be able to change all these links to something like

`href="/Book-online.htm?cid=[newPageId]"`

The id of the pages have changed so I need to update those as well but that's not a problem.

I was thinking something like `preg_replace` might work but I've little experience with regular expressions.

I'm open to any other solutions if you have them.

Answer (score 1):

If the content is HTML its better to use HTML Parser like DOM Parser to parse it. If you've non HTML content and are just looking to replace HREFs then you can use this preg_replace:

```
// Assuming you have old to new id mapping sotred in an array $idmap

$new = preg_replace_callback('/(href=")book-online(\?cid=)([^"]+)"/i',
           function($m) {
               static $idmap = array("123" => "321", "645" => "546");
               return $m[1] . 'Book-online.htm' . $m[2] . $idmap[$m[3]];
           }, $content);
```

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/o4hpnU

Comment: Thanks for you answer, Just one thing, how would I update the final part of cid=123 to cid=321